# ¿La función glm genera y almacena los ODD ratio del modelo estimado?

Tags: r, model

Cuando ejecutas un modelo lineal generalizado con la función `glm(*)`, esta te devuelve un objeto con varios valores importantes sobre el modelo. Sin embargo, no encuentro los valores de los **ODD ratio** de cada variable necesarios para poder interpretar el modelo. He mirado en la documentación pero no he encontrado estos valores y me extraña muchísimo que no se incluya en el objeto `glm`. Entonces, **¿Debo generar yo mismo una columna con los ODD ratio o están en el objeto que se genera al ejecutar `glm()`?**

Dejo un link con la documentación que estoy consultando:
[documentación glm()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/glm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que si te interesan los odd ratios o razones de momio estás trabajando con un modelo logit. En ese caso los OR son los coeficientes exponenciados y los puedes ver con `exp(coefficients(modelo))`.

R reporta (correctamente) como coeficientes al logaritmo de las razones de probabilidad, de ese modo es más directa la interpretación de la pendiente (el signo del coeficiente). Claro, es más difícil de interpretar en términos de magnitud de la variación y para eso en necesario exponenciarlos.

Answer (score 0):

En un modelo econometrico, no es necesario exponenciarlos, pero hay que tener muy en cuenta que cambia la interpretación de los coeficientes.

El modelo Nivel-Nivel representa las variables en su forma original (regresión en forma lineal). Es decir, un cambio de una unidad en X, afecta en β1 unidades a Y.
El modelo Nivel-Log se interpreta como un incremento del 1% de cambio en X es asociado a un cambio en Y de 0,01· β1.

El modelo Log-Nivel es el menor frecuentemente utilizado y se conoce como la semielasticidad de Y respecto a X. Se interpreta como un incremento de 1 unidad en X es asociado a un cambio en Y de (100·β1 )%.

El modelo Log-Log es atribuye a β1 la elasticidad de Y, respecto a X. Se interpreta como un incremento del 1% en X es asociado a un cambio en Y de B1%.